# How to find top 6 elements in an array in C

Tags: c, sorting

I am trying to find top 6 elements from an array with their ordering number.

```
    int x=0;

for (int k = 0; k < 6; k++) //
{
    for (i = 1; i <= 90; i++)
    {
        if (sorted[k] < holder[i] && i >= x)
        {
            sorted[k] = holder[i];
            x = i; //
        }
    }
}
```

But this does not work. I want it to give me output like 43->7 15 ->3 etc..

Comment: Simply sort your array, get the top 6 elements and then find the indexes for those elements from the original array.

Comment: What does "top 6" mean?  what is their "ordering number"?  What do `holder` and `sorted` contain?  what is an example of the output you are looking for?

Comment: @wallyk Holder contains the all elements. Sorted is an array for 6 elements to be hold. By top 6 i mean biggest 6 elements. Ordering number is for example if biggest element is holder[46], then 46 is our ordering number.

Comment: You can use [partial sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_sorting).

Comment: I am a newbie @MikeKobit could you help me with the code ive given

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't written C in a while, but here is a simple solution that modifies the array in place and uses selection sort to select the `k` highest numbers in the array and moves them to the front. It keeps an array of indices that correspond to where the number originally was and applies the same swaps to it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ELEMENTS 10

void main(void)
{
    // example input for execution
    int numbers[10] = {9,4,5,1,8,2,3,6,0,7};
    // tracks ordering of indices
    int indexes[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int k = 6;

    int i, j;
    int max, temp;

    // Partial selection sort, move k max elements to front
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        max = i;
        // Find next max index
        for (j = i+1; j < ELEMENTS; j++)
        {
            if (numbers[j] > numbers[max])  {
                max = j;
            }
        }
        // Swap numbers in input array
        temp = numbers[i];
        numbers[i] = numbers[max];
        numbers[max] = temp;
        // Swap indexes in tracking array
        temp = indexes[i];
        indexes[i] = indexes[max];
        indexes[max] = temp;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        printf("%d -> %d\n", indexes[i], numbers[i]);
    }
}
```

And the output:

```
0 -> 9
4 -> 8
9 -> 7
7 -> 6
2 -> 5
1 -> 4
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you aren't looking for a code-only answer, but this will work:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// return index of max element
int max_index( int* vec, int sz )
{
    int idx, max, i;

    if(!sz) return -1;

    idx = 0;
    max = vec[0];

    for(i=1; i<sz; ++i)
    {
        if( vec[i] > max )
        {
            max = vec[i];
            idx = i;
        }
    }

    return idx;
}

// return indexes of N top elements
void top( int* vec, int sz, int* out_vec, int N )
{
    int i, *tmp, idx;

    tmp = (int*) malloc( sz*sizeof(int) );
    memcpy( tmp, vec, sz*sizeof(int) );

    for(i=0; i<N; ++i )
    {
        idx = max_index(tmp,sz);
        out_vec[i]=idx;
        tmp[idx] = INT_MIN;
    }

    free(tmp);
}
```

see it live [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b00a28024dad9e3)

Comment: Actually I was looking for a code-only answer. But can we stick with C please? I will not use C++ for this project so can you help me?

Comment: @sp2danny, the OP is looking for a C answer, not C++. Vectors would be a good C++ solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

Say that you are given an array `numbers`. Then create an array `indexes` with the same size as numbers in such a way that its values are equal to their indexes. Here is an illustration:

```
numbers = [ 1, 7, 3, 9, 2, 0 ]
indexes = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

Sort `numbers` in descending order, performing the same operations on `indexes`. In the end, you should end up with something like this:

```
numbers = [ 9, 7, 3, 2, 1, 0 ]
indexes = [ 3, 1, 2, 4, 0, 5 ]
```

Finally, all you need to do is work with the first six elements of these arrays.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

int contains(int array[], int array_size, int value)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] == value)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

    return FALSE;
}

int main()
{
    int numbers[] = { 1, 7, 3, 9, 2, 0 };
    int indexes[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    int numbers_size = 6;

    int largest[] = { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 };
    int largest_index = 0;

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        int j;
        int max_index = -1;
        int max = -2147483648;

        for (j = 0; j < numbers_size; j++)
        {
            if (numbers[j] >= max && contains(largest, numbers_size, j) == FALSE)
            {
                max_index = j;
                max = numbers[max_index];
            }
        }

        largest[largest_index++] = max_index;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d->%d\n", largest[i], numbers[largest[i]]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see but can we do this without sorting?

Comment: You can iterate the array six times, each time recording the largest number whose index is not already in a list of recorded numbers. I might edit this answer with sample code later.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer I have for you.

I would love some constructive criticism on it from anyone who can provide some.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int numbers[10] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    int *ptrNumbers[10];
    int i=0;
    for(; i < 10; i++){
        ptrNumbers[i] = &numbers[i]; // assign the addresses
    }

    int topSix[6];

    int topSixIndex=0;
    for(; topSixIndex < 6; topSixIndex++){
        int **best = NULL; // Pointer to the pointer to the value.

        int checkIndex=0;
        for(; checkIndex < 10; checkIndex++){
            if(ptrNumbers[checkIndex] != NULL){
                if(!best){
                    /* best is not yet defined */
                    best = &ptrNumbers[checkIndex];
                    // best now points to the pointer for numbers[checkIndex]
                }else if(*ptrNumbers[checkIndex] > **best){
                    // this else if statement could be attached to the main if as
                    // an or condition, but I've separated it for readability.
                    best = &ptrNumbers[checkIndex];
                    // best now points to the pointer for numbers[checkIndex]
                }
            }
        }
        // assign the topSix position and flag the ptrNumbers
        topSix[topSixIndex] = **best;
        *best = NULL;
    }

    // now we'll print the numbers
    for(topSixIndex = 0; topSixIndex < 6; topSixIndex++){
        printf("%d\n", topSix[topSixIndex]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Essentially the program works like this: Given an array of ten numbers, a second array is constructed to house pointers to those 10 numbers. A third array is then constructed to house the values of the top 6 numbers. A for loop is then initialized to loop 6 times to find the highest unrecorded value. When the highest value is found by looping the pointer array, the value is assigned to the next index of the top six array. Once that value is added, the pointer array's index that points to the top six value is then assigned to NULL. This acts as a flag insuring that the value will not be added again. Finally, all numbers are printed out.

After running this code, the output I received was:

```
9
8
7
6
5
4
```

---

**Edit:** as a note, the ordering number's can be stored in a second array. You would simply need to track the `checkIndex` of the highest value and then assign it to a second array which contained the index values.

Comment: No problems. Glad it could help. I apologize because it's a bit messy.

Comment: Interesting idea, but I think it's performance sucks.  Instead of an array of pointers, you could simply copy the data, and remove an element from consideration by setting it to `INT_MIN`.  That makes it compare false the next time through (unless all the other values are also `INT_MIN`).

Comment: In practice, more efficient algorithms are possible (which touch the data less often).  If you want only a few high elements from a large array, keep a priority queue as you loop through.  If you want the top half or top third, do a partial sort.

Comment: @PeterCordes, oh, yeah. This answer was written while I was still learning C several years ago. I certainly wouldn't stand behind this solution as being super-efficient. It appears that I was moreso interested in playing around with pointers, but who knows what I was thinking back then. Nonetheless, I guess you answered the call for, _"some constructive criticism"_ ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Make an array of struct that contain data and index, then sort it and pick up first or last 6 elements to output.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use bubblesort (and keep a function holding all the original indexes) and then just make it show the 6 first number of both arrays (from the indexes array and from the array you sorted itself)